# I don't understand why I'm getting section name in the header?

Tags: pdftex, luatex, scrbook

[image: Chapter one]

In chapter 1, I don't see any header (with section or chapter name in it.)
But in chapter two, I see the section name. I'm not sure why this is happening.
I even tried to clear the headers and footers using the `\fancyhead{}` and `\fancyfoot{}`.
But still not working.

[image: Chapter two]

```
% !TeX root = MasterThesis.tex
% !TeX encoding = utf8
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openany]{scrbook}
%page layout
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt]{chapter}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\fontspec{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{babel}
\newcommand\fh{\babelhyphen{hard}}
\usepackage{url}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\title{Seamless Firmware Update Over the Air}
\author{Vijay Bhargava B}
\date{February 2023}
%\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{
%   \def\\{}%
%   \def\texttt#1{<#1>}%
%}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\newcommand{\setupname}[1][\chaptername]{
    \titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\vspace{1ex}}{\bfseries#1~\thecontentslabel:\quad}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}[]
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\include{00_1_Declaration_honest}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\frontmatter
\include{00_1_Abstract}
\setupname
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\include{01_Introduction/01_Introduction}
\include{02_Theoretical/02_Theoretical_Background}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's hard to know what's causing the problem here because your example cannot be compiled. To make it easier for others to help you, you should provide a complete (yet minimal) example that reproduces the problem and that can be compiled on its own.

Comment: I'm sorry, new to this. Minimum than this? I see only preamble and 2 images.

Comment: Your document does not compile: there is no `\end{document}`, and the `\include`d files are missing. Your problem has to do with chapters and sections, yet your sample file does not contain a single of these commands. You load the `lipsum` package, which is intended to generate dummy text, but don't use it. Before posting code, try it in a new directory and check that it compiles and shows the problem that you want to have solved.